# Wrap SOAP tags/headers around XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to find XSLT that can do the following.

I'm trying to wrap an XML message in a quick soap envelope (xml).  The source XML is not set in stone, so the XSLT should not care what the XML is. It does need to strip the XML Declaration off the top of the XML.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
    <bar />
</foo>
```

transformed to:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
          <foo>
            <bar />
          </foo>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

Example 2:

```
<lady>
  <and>
   <the>
    <tramp />
   </the>
  </and>
</lady>



<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
         <lady>
           <and>
              <the>
                  <tramp />
             </the>
           </and>
         </lady>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/*"/>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs this XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <lady xmlns="">
         <and>
            <the>
               <tramp/>
            </the>
         </and>
      </lady>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this (which is similar to Phoenixblade9's answer, but doesn't use `xsl:element`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good point, I changed mine to simplify it.  I do prefer using xsl:element in most cases, but I don't think it works here.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 - I'm not sure if `xsl:element` would work for XSLT 1.0 with the default namespace needing to be output. It would in 2.0 though. Let me know if you would like an example.

Comment: Yeah, I was having trouble with multiple namespaces.  I didn't know this was a solution, and I adjusted my answer to be more accurate.  Thanks!